# Spring boot Oracle JPA set QueryTimeout

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, timeout

I'm using Spring Boot with Ojdbc8 18.3.0.0.0
With Hikari Datasource and JPA, all query work fine.
But now I need to set Query timeout for all database query
I was try many way:

```
javax.persistence.query.timeout=1000
spring.transaction.default-timeout=1
spring.jdbc.template.query-timeout=1
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=1
```

Config Class:

```
@Configuration
public class JPAQueryTimeout {

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout}")
    private int queryTimeout;   

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setDefaultTimeout(queryTimeout); //Put 1 seconds timeout
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Query:

```
List<Integer> llll = manager.createNativeQuery("select test_sleep(5) from dual")
            .setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 1).getResultList();
```

The database task take 5 second before return value, but in all of case, no error occor.

Could anyone tell me how to set query timeout?

Comment: Can you try adding `@Transactional(timeout = 1)` on the method that is querying the db? Be aware that the method must be `public`.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I was try and it's work. The exption occur:

org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
...
ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet
....

Comment: But why the exeption is: "ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet" 
instead of "ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation" ?

Comment: Hmm, that is weird, can you try to drop the usage of `PlatformTransactionManager` ? & use maybe proper repositories or queries with spring data jpa? & drop any other extra config you added to enforce the timeout, just use `@Transactional` with `timeout` on vanilla spring data jpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the simplest solution, that is using the `timeout` value within `@Transactional`;

```
@Transactional(timeout = 1) // in seconds (so that is 1 second timeout)
public Foo runQuery(String id) {
    String result = repo.findById(id);
    // other logic
}
```

> Be aware that the method annotated with `@Transactional` must be `public` for it to work properly

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.
After using that Anonation, the query has been timeout, the exeption occur is "ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet"
And then I put System.setProperty("oracle.net.disableOob", "true"); . Now it work fine with exeption throw: "ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation"

Comment: @user3611168 I see, I saw that solution as well, but consider dropping the weird structures like `PlatformTransactionManager` and using proper spring data jpa features, then you might not need to set that property

Comment: I was remove all of other config when using your suggestion,Thank you. My problem has been resolved.

Comment: how can we do it when no transaction is required but only timeout?